# How can i show the image on full screen when i click any item of image in the gridview?

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have a list of T-shirt  Image which is displayed  in grid view.Now what i have to do is when i click any item of the image   in the gridview,display the image in full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to achieve this is :
make intent that display images from gallery: for that code is :

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(intent, TFRequestCodes.GALLERY);
```

after that override the method onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        }
```

in that method you can get images ids and whatever you want to fetch :
and you can also display in it in your activity: